# malloc()/ Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: malloc

I always have confusion regarding malloc function, how much ever I read there are always loose ends , can someone please help me understand the use of malloc() and a scenario where it can be used.

Thank you

Comment: This is covered in detail in most introductory C books. If you have a specific question about one of your "loose ends", ask about that - your question is currently too broad.

Comment: Dynamic means that you can free this memory after you don't need it. But I think wikipedia can help you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

malloc() is used for dynamic memory allocation.
So, We can allocate the memory needed when we use.
(Instead of static allocation like int[1024])

For instance,
When we read the document file and we have to do something for every words, but we don't know the contents.
In that time, we should use dynamic memory allocation.